# Register Jackson Serializer for all except the root node

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

I have a structure of elements, they all implement the interface "Urifyable". Let's say we have trains and the current station.

```
public class Train implements Urifyable {
    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return "My Train";
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public Station getCurrentStation() {
        return StationPool.get("1");
    }
    public String getUri() {
        return "/train/1";
    }
}

public class Station implements Urifyable {
    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return "My Station";
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public Train[] getCurrentTrains() {
        return /* some code to get an array of trains */;
    }
    public String getUri() {
        return "/station/1";
    }
}
```

If I use that with dropwizard+jason+jax-rs, I can register a custom serializer like this:

```
final SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule");
myModule.addKeySerializer(Urifyable.class, new UrifyableSerializer());
environment.getObjectMapper().registerModule(myModule);
```

The UrifyableSerializer does prevent the generic serialize logic of jackson and returns only the string representation of the getUri method.

How do I enable this serializer only for the everything except the root node? Because at the moment it will return

```
"/station/1"
```

if I request a station, but it should return:

```
{
   "name": "My Station",
   "currentTrains": [
       "/train/1", 
       "/train/2",
       "/train/3",
   ]
}
```

and for "/train/1" it should return:

```
{
    "name": "My Train",
    "currentStation": "/station/1"
}
```

Comment: Instead of using special serializer, you can define your `currentTrains` field as List<Urifyable> instead of List<Train>. I'm actually not 100% sure that'd work though, not sure if Jackson will crash or just serialize using `getUri`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to specify serializer to use for the property, and not type. That is, instead of registering via module, you declare it like so:

```
public class Station implements Urifyable {
  // note: since it's array, use 'contentUsing'; for POJOs it'd be 'using'
  @JsonSerialize(contentUsing=MyTrainSerializer.class)
  public Train[] getCurrentTrains() {
     return /* some code to get an array of trains */;
  }
}
```

this way serializer only applies to serialization of values reached through that specific POJO property.